# Can I read and edit files that belong to the website folder using only html and javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, asp.net

[image: Image of website folder]

I am creating a website that must be able to login using the credentials that are saved in a text file(login.txt).After logging in the person must be able to add and remove images(images folder).
These images will then later be used to create a gallery that all users will be able to view.

What I want to know is can i achieve these results by only making use of HTML and JavaScript or must i also make use of server side languages like php or asp.net ?

note : I have done a good amount of research and still wasn't able to find an accurate answer for this question.

Any advice will be useful. Thanks ahead...

Comment: You are going to need something on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** You have to use a server

I assume you already know Javascript, so my advice is use Node.js.

You have to use a server side language because other users need to see the gallery , besides the ones that are uploading. So you can't use localStorage to save the images, because the front-end is private to the user, not global to every user (like a database or a server).

*Some suggestions:*

- Use a database for user details, is faster, safer, and more maintainable
- Define a Rest API on the server-side
- On the front-end make a Single page application (using desired framework/libraries), using TDD principle

Answer (score 0):

You should to use a server side language.

And if you save the credentials in a text file then anyone can reach these infos with that file url.  ( Eg: http://yoursite.com/login.txt )

Comment: Unless, of course, the web server is configured not to serve that file.

Comment: Thanks for the advice...

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to know is can i achieve these results by only making use of HTML and JavaScript or must i also make use of server side languages like php or asp.net ?

You'll need *something* on the server. That something might be:

- Web server software that supports using the `PUT` verb to put files in a directory on the server. The general term for this is DAV or, in the web context, [WebDAV](http://www.webdav.org/). Apache, for instance, supports it with [`mod_dav`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dav.html). I've never tried it, but it may be possible to set up Apache with simple authentication (probably not with a *plain text* username/password file, though) and enable WebDAV for authenticated users. Your client-side code could then send `PUT` requests via ajax.
- A server-side programming environment of some kind whether that's PHP, ASP.Net, NodeJS, or something else.
- A content management system of some kind that already provides the ability you would otherwise write.